# Do we have C++20 ranges library in GCC 9?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++20

Do we have support for C++20 ranges library in the newly released GCC 9?

I copied the example code below for ranges library from: 
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges

```
#include <vector>
#include <ranges>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> ints{0,1,2,3,4,5};
  auto even = [](int i){ return 0 == i % 2; };
  auto square = [](int i) { return i * i; };

  for (int i : ints | std::view::filter(even) | std::view::transform(square)) {
    std::cout << i << ' ';
  }
}
```

But when compiled with g++ 9.1 (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS  (Bionic Beaver)), it complains that `<ranges>` cannot be found:

```
$ g++ -std=c++2a cpp2a.cpp 
cpp2a.cpp:2:10: fatal error: ranges: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <ranges>
      |          ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Am I missing something?

And will the ranges library arrive at some point of time with the GCC 9 series?

Comment: Completely unrelated mini rant: Why does C++ have to kill the elegance of all of the (otherwise simple) features it chooses to adopt? Between Ruby, Kotlin, Rust, Swift, Java, and C#, there's already so much good design on lambda and range syntax. This could have been something as nice as `(0...5).select { |x| x % 2 == 0 }.map { |x| x*x }`. `std::adverb::There std::verb::are std::adjective::just std::adjective::too std::adjective::many std::noun::scopes.`

Comment: @Alexander: Well no, it could not have been anything like that.  A library cannot extend the syntax of the language.  Now, you can easily write `using std::view::filter` and then use `filter` without having to qualify it.  In fact, it's recommended to do so, because fully-qualified names disable Koenig lookup.

Comment: @Alexander: The main point against your suggestion is that you propose a *change to the language*, whereas this is simply a new library. Also, bound methods are rather restrictive to the sorts of flexibility that C++ allows and C++ style regularly exploits: thus the overloaded operator model. And you can import individual names anyways.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> Am I missing something?

No.

> And will the ranges library arrive at some point of time with the gcc-9 series?

<s>It's possible but seems unlikely.</s> This did not happen. The first release to support Ranges in gcc was gcc 10.1.

---

Ranges is an *enormous* library. It's still 2019, the official C++20 standard still won't even be shipped for another year and a half. It'll take a while for it to get implemented in the major standard library implementations. We'll just have to wait.

If you want to start using Ranges, you can use [Range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) (specifically the `v1.0-beta` branch) or you can find an implementation of C++20 Ranges at [cmcstl2](https://github.com/CaseyCarter/cmcstl2) (this is Casey Mysterious Carter's implementation).

You can also periodically check cppreference's [compiler/library tracking page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) (which at the time of writing shows no libraries having implemented the One Ranges proposal, but nevertheless does show quite a few C++20 features as having been implemented by the various library vendors).

Comment: It's also worth noting that ranges heavily rely on concepts that currently only exist in their TS incarnation in GCC.

Answer (score 14):

Per [Table 1.7. C++ 2020 Implementation Status](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2020)

> The One Ranges Proposal   P0896R4

the version is 10.1.  That means that you'll need to upgrade to at least that version to get the feature.

Answer (score 14):

g++10 supports `<ranges>` feature along with a [number of other c++20 features](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/changes.html).

```
#include <vector>
#include <ranges>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> ints{0,1,2,3,4,5};
  auto even = [](int i){ return 0 == i % 2; };
  auto square = [](int i) { return i * i; };

  for (int i : ints | std::views::filter(even) | std::views::transform(square)) {
    std::cout << i << ' ';
  }
}

$ g++-10 -Wall -Wextra -std=c++20 ranges.cpp 
$ ./a.out 
0 4 16
```

On Ubuntu, the packages are now available. To install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install gcc-10 g++-10
```

However, g++-10 does not have support for *all* features. See the [Table 1.8. C++ 2020 Library Features](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2020) for features list supported.

Answer (score 5):

GCC 10 has been released as stable in March (with a [version update 10.1 on May 7, 2020](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/changes.html)).

This version supports `ranges`.

The [compiler/library tracking page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) is up to date as well.

Thus your code sample* compiles: https://godbolt.org/z/MPxBMs

```
#include <vector>
#include <ranges>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> ints{0,1,2,3,4,5,6};
  auto even = [](int i){ return 0 == i % 2; };
  auto square = [](int i) { return i * i; };

  for (int i : ints | std::views::filter(even) | std::views::transform(square)) {
    std::cout << i << ' ';
  }
}
```

*: with a small fix, since the namespace alias is `std::views` not `std::view`.

I tested this with a local installation compiled *by hand* on macOS.

```
g++-10.1 -std=c++20 -Wall test.cpp
```

Comment: How did you get g++-10 on your Mac?

Comment: I did it *by hand*: to do so, you can read https://gcc.gnu.org/install/ .

Comment: In my case, it was: download gcc sources and then `mkdir build && cd build && ../configure --prefix=your_install_path --enable-checking=release --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-multilib --with-sysroot=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk --program-suffix=-10.1 && make install` . Wait ~30mn and it should be ready to use.